# Laravel 5.4 Pagination

Tags: bootstrap-4, laravel-5.4

I would like to add pagination to my admin index page with children ordered by id desc.
here is the index method in ChildrenController:

```
public function index()
{
    // $children = Child::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
    // $children = $children->paginate(50);
    $children = Child::paginate(50);
    return view('welcome', compact('children'));
}
```

so how can I paginate the result of this query

$children = Child::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();

this is the view code:

```
@section('content')

    @foreach($children as $child)

        @include('children.child')

    @endforeach

    {{ $children->links() }}

@endsection
```

and this is the actual view which is not sexy:

[image]

I would like to have it like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can customize the the layout of the laravel pagination. 
However, the easiest way to customize the pagination views is by exporting them to your  resources/views/vendor directory using the vendor:publish command:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination
```

This command will place the views in the resources/views/vendor/pagination directory.

For more information please follow [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view)

Comment: how can I paginate this query $children = Child::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();

Comment: You can use this code
Child::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(20)

Answer (score 0):

you can as well locate the `LengthAwarePaginator.php` file and change

```
 $presenter = $presenter ?: new BootstrapThreePresenter($this);
```

to

```
 $presenter = $presenter ?: new BootstrapFourPresenter($this);
```